# How can I pass integer through the buffer?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I want to create a socket that can read some numbers rather than string so that I can perform some manipulations on them.
How can I send integer instead of string
This is my current program:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
int sockfd, newsockfd, port, clilen;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

if (argc < 2)
error("ERROR, no port provided\n");
port = atoi(argv[1]);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
error("ERROR opening socket");

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port); //host to network

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
error("ERROR binding to socket");

listen(sockfd,2);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
int n;
void* buffer[256];
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);


if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("Message received:%d\n",d);

n = write(newsockfd,buffer, strlen((char *)buffer));
if (n < 0)
error("ERROR writing back to socket");

return 0;}
```

I tried this:

```
int n= 5;
 write(newsockfd,&n, sizeof(int));
```

But on the client side (also a void* buffer), it doesn't seem to read anything. Can anyone help me how can I rectify this?

One solution could be to pass strings then convert to int etc. But is that the proper way?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) consistently indent the code: indent after every  (even optional) opening braces '{'.  unindent before every (even optional) closing braces '}'.

Comment: functions: `listen()` and `accept()` need to have their returned values check to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing all the needed `#include` statements.   When asking a question of the variety: `why doesn't my code work`, post code the cleanly compiles, is small, and still shows the problem.

Comment: Supposedly the code is receiving a binary number (probably 4 or 8 bytes).  Such a number can have NUL bytes.  For instance, the number 1 would be: `00000001` or `01000000` depending on the endianness of the sender.  therefore, this statement: `n = write(newsockfd,buffer, strlen((char *)buffer));` will not work.  Suggest: `n = write(newsockfd,buffer, n));`

Comment: the posted code is using a variable `d`, but that variable is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: this line: `void* buffer[256];` is declaring an array of 256 void pointers, you probably want: `char buffer[256];`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, 2, 255, 256.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the `read()` function does not append a NUL byte to the input buffer, so there is no reason to declare the buffer to be 256 bytes, then have the `read() limited to 255 bytes

Comment: this is the syntax for the `error()` function, as prototyped in the `error.h` header file: `void error(int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);`   so all the calls to `error()` are not correct.

Comment: this line: `error("ERROR, no port provided\n");`  is not very informative.  suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <portNum>", argv[0]); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is two-fold:

The first problem is that the declaration `void* buffer[256]` declares `buffer` to be an array of 256 pointers to `void`, not really what's intended I guess. Instead if you want an array of 256 bytes just do `char buffer[256]`.

The second problem is that on the receiving side you treat the data as a string, but it's not a string it's a binary data value.

The second problem can be solved in two ways: Either you convert the integer to a string, and send that string. Or you receive the raw data of the integer, and convert it to an `int`. The first solution involves `sprintf`, and the other solution involves either `memcpy` or pointers and casting.

---

For the first solution above, you could do something like this:

```
char temp[32];
snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "%d", n);
write(newsockfd, temp, sizeof temp);
```

On the receiving end you read it as a string:

```
char buffer[32];
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
if (n <= 0)
{
    // Error or connection closed
}

// TODO: Since TCP is a streaming protocol, we could actually receive
//       less than the number of bytes we asked to read, so we need
//       to read in a loop

// Print the received data as a string
printf("Received '%s'\n", buffer);  // Works because the sender sent with the terminator

// Convert to integer
int i = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
printf("Received %d\n", i);
```

---

For the second solution above, send the integer value as raw binary data as you already do, but when receiving this do something like

```
char buffer[32];
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
if (n <= 0)
{
    // Error or connection closed
}

// TODO: Since TCP is a streaming protocol, we could actually receive
//       less than the number of bytes we asked to read, so we need
//       to read in a loop

int i = *(int *) buffer;
printf("Received %d\n", i);
```

Note that this second solution, as it is written in this answer, relies that both the sender and the receiver have the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), as well as the same size for `int` (which might not always be the case).

The safest way is generally to convert to a string on the sending side, and receive the string as, well, a string. I.e. the first solution.

Comment: Agree about safest way is generally to convert to a string, but this code does not send a single string, but array contents that are certainly null terminated, yet the receiving end does not "know" the length of the array.  OTOH, if both ends "know" the buffer size is 31+1, then why not "know" the `int` size instead - simplier.  To pipe data "safely" , do not depend on magic numbers like 32.  When sending _strings_, also send the final null character.  Else send size information first and then the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to modify the lucid answer [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) provided.

```
int value, todo = sizeof(value);
char *p = (void*) &value;

while ( (n = read(newsockfd, p, todo)) < todo ) {
  if( n == 0 ) { /* handle eof and break */ }
  if( n < 0  ) { /* handle error and break */ }

  todo -= n;
  p += n
}

if( todo == 0 ) {
  printf("Received %d\n", value);
}
```

You know how many bytes you're receiving, so there's no reason to read more.  The loop deals with case he warns of: that **read**(2) may fail to read all 4 bytes (unlikely in this case, but not in general).

You can always get `char *` from `void *`, and pass any pointer to a function accepting `void *`.  What you cannot do, portably, is

```
char buffer[32];
...
int i = *(int *) buffer;
```

because a character array is not guaranteed to have integer alignment.  On some architectures, that provokes SIGBUS.  If you read into character array, the safe way to interpret those bytes as an integer is

```
memcpy(&i, buffer, sizeof i);
```